# Use async/await with Microsoft.Bcl.Async: the type or namespace name 'async' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I need to use async/await on the .net framework 4, VS2013 (web forms application). I installed Microsoft.Bcl.Async via nuget, but I get always:

> *The type or namespace name 'async' could not be found*

And if I try to define a namespace like:

```
using Microsoft.Threading.Tasks;
```

I get

> *The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'*

So how I can use Microsoft.Bcl.Async?

Comment: The threading namespace is `System.Threading` not `Microsoft.Threading`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Microsoft.Bcl.Async on ASP.NET. Even if you get it to compile. it will have undefined behavior at runtime.

This is because some core ASP.NET types had to change to support `async`. The NuGet package only contains the types the compiler needs; it does not patch the ASP.NET runtime.

Comment: Thanks, so isn't there a way to use async/await on asp.net 4.0?

Comment: @DevT: No, there isn't. For ASP.NET, you need at least 4.5.